# Allow nested array in a document to share identical objects with other docs in collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, duplicates, schema, unique

I have a schema for a picklist that looks like this:

```
const PicklistSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    list_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    author_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    author_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    items: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
        default: [],
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        enum: [
            'initialized',
            'submitted',
            'retrieving',
            'retrieved',
            'complete',
        ],
        required: true,
        default: 'initialized',
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now(),
    },
});
```

An object that gets inserted into the "items" array looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "testitem1",
    "size": "00",
    "desc": "This item should only be used in a dev environment, for testing purposes",
    "upcs": [ "testitem1", "test" ],
    "id": "test"
}
```

I create a new picklist and add the test item, and it works. If I create a second picklist and try to add the same test item, I get:

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: picklists.picklists index: items.id_1 dup key: { items.id: "test" }
```

The error will be `{ items.id: null }` if I try to create a new picklist without adding anything to the first.

I've tried adding `unique: false` to the items array, and several other options (like writing the subschema of the items array and making `id: { type: String, unique: false }`), but nothing prevents that error. I was reading about sparse indexes, but I'm not sure if that's the solution, and if so, how to incorporate it into the code.

How do I make mongo less opinionated about what goes into the items array of each picklist document?

I can delete every picklist in the collection, and the error will occur if the second (or third, etc.) picklist that I create tries to add an item contained in the first.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a lot of similar errors were caused by artifacts in the collection from previous impositions on data by the schema, and were resolved by dropping the collection and creating a new one, so I tried that, and it worked.